# How do mission planners determine where to put trajectory control maneuvers (mid-course maneuvers)?

Tags: trajectory-design

It seems to me that one could select a time for a TCM/MCM by finding the point in a reference trajectory where the velocity required to alter the position and velocity of the next trajectory point is minimized.

That is, for the state transition matrix $$\Phi(t_k, t_{k+1}) = \begin{bmatrix}\Phi_{rr} & \Phi_{rv} \\ \Phi_{vr} & \Phi_{vv} \end{bmatrix}\,\textrm{,}$$ we write $$\delta\mathrm{v}_k = \Phi_{vr}\delta\mathrm{r}_{k+1} + \Phi_{vv}\delta\mathrm{v}_{k+1}$$ and find the point that minimizes the magnitude $\|\delta\mathrm{v}_k\|$ (subject to some constraints, e.g. requiring that $\|\delta\mathrm{v}_k\| > \Delta v_\text{min}$ for the spacecraft's control system).

Then one could continue iterating backwards until at $t_0$, forming a chain of TCMs, each producing the largest possible alteration in state $\mathrm{x}_{k+1}$ with the smallest possible correction at $t_k$.

Is this generally how these corrections are designed? What other considerations are there?

I've been told before that navigational uncertainty also comes into play, that TCMs can also reduce state estimate uncertainty, and that there are constraints on TCMs produced by state estimate uncertainty at the nominal TCM time.

Is there some sort of canonical resource providing information about TCM design?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, trajectory correction maneuvers would never be needed. Ideally, the spacecraft's position/velocity state before and after then coarse maneuver would be known perfectly and instantaneously, and the accumulated delta V applied by the spacecraft would be perfectly applied and perfectly measured. Nearly ideally, the ideal time to perform a trajectory correction maneuver would be immediately after or even during the coarse maneuver or trajectory correction maneuver at hand.

This is one of the many places in space exploration where the best is the enemy of good enough.

The ideal / near ideal is not achievable. The spacecraft's state, even in free drift, is never perfect, and the propagated state from the last good update is even less than perfect. The accumulated delta V measured by the spacecraft's accelerometers is not perfect. Trying to achieve the unachievable, or even coming close, is ridiculously expensive.

The metric posed in the question demands the unachievable ideal. The reality is that a number of other metrics come into play. One key issue is that it takes time and expensive resources to determine the degree of imperfection in the most recent coarse maneuver / trajectory control maneuver. NASA's Deep Space Network (or a European / Russian / Chinese / Indian / commercial equivalent) does a fairly good job of estimating the trajectory of a spacecraft. They do an even better job given multiple connections separated by time. The data collected by the space network have to be sent to and processed by the spacecraft's ground control center.  Keeping such a center fully operational on a 24/7/365 basis is very expensive. If possible, it is much better to keep the amount of time where a fully-staffed control center is needed to a minimum.

This suggests a different metric than the metric proposed in the question. That alternative metric is economic cost: dollars/euros/rubles/rupees/yuans/currency of choice. This alternative metric might indicate, for example, that the cheap accelerometer one planned to use has a hidden cost in terms of space network contacts and/or control center staffing, or that the expensive accelerometer one expected to need is overkill.